# Consumer heartbeat time configuration in CANopen

Tags: can, canopen

I have the following situation. I have a **master** (consumer) and a **slave** (producer), the slave has to be between **nodes 1-127**, in this case the slave is in the node **125**.

I'm trying to syncronize both of them, for that, after some research I found about the heartbeat function.

I'm prety new to CANopen, so I've tried changing values in the `master.dcf` file. If you know about CANopen you will know that there are several parameters that are the same for everybody, so you can configure them in the way you need. In this case I've modified the 1017h (Producer heartbeat time) parameter by changing the `DefaultValue` to **1000 ms** so every second I get a heartbeat from the producer (slave). Here you can see the `master.dcf` where I made the change:

```
[1017]
ParameterName=Producer heartbeat time
DataType=0x0006
AccessType=rw
DefaultValue=1000
```

My problem is making the same with the master (consumer). For this, in the `master.dcf` the parameter `1016h` (Consumer heartbeat time) is suposed to function the same way as the `1017h` but I don't know what to change in here in order to get a hearbeat from the master every second. Here is the `1016h` in the `master.dcf`:

```
[1016]
ParameterName=Consumer heartbeat time
ObjectType=0x08
DataType=0x0007
AccessType=rw
CompactSubObj=127

[1016Value]
NrOfEntries=0
```

As mentioned, I've tried modifying the value of `NrOfEntries`, but I don't think this is somthing relevant to my case, so I left it as it was (`NrOfEntries = 0`).

I've also tried with other two parameters: `1006h` and `1007h`.

```
[1006]
ParameterName=Communication cycle period
DataType=0x0007
AccessType=rw
DefaultValue=0

[1007]
ParameterName=Synchronous window length
DataType=0x0007
AccessType=rw
DefaultValue=0
```

Both of them have a starting value of **0**, and I've tried changing them to **1** but I still can't get to see the hearbeat of the slave.

To see what happens in **CAN** I'm using `candump can0` in a terminal and I can see every message of the comunication, in the next image you can see a part of the comunication: [image: Image candump]

As you can see in the image, the line `can0 701 [1] 05` is the line of the producers heartbeat that appears every second, as configured. The other lines are for **CAN** initialization (**NMT** messages) and valve opening and clossing.

In case someone thinks it's important. As a master I'm using a **NVIDIA Xavier** and as an slave I have a **CR2041** ifm module, to where I've connected some valves to be controlled. The comunication happens when I execute the application that controls the valves.

If you need more information to help me ask for it without problems.

Comment: "I'm trying to syncronize both of them" What do you mean? Heartbeat isn't to be used for that purpose, it is for supervision and trouble-shooting. It sounds like the feature you are actually looking for is the PDO SYNC message.

Comment: I agree. Heartbeat can be understood as a communication watchdog.

Answer (score 2):

I've added comments next to the CANopen dump output (next time please add the dump in text form).

Red comment: Master (node 1)
Yellow comment: NMT (most probably from the master)
Green comment: Slave (node 125)

[image]

As you can see, it's not the slave (node 125) that's sending the bootup and heartbeat messages, but the master (node 1). There is nothing wrong with the master sending heartbeat messages. But in your case you said you wanted the slave to be the heartbeat producer and the master to be the heartbeat consumer.

In order to configure the slave (node 125) as heartbeat producer, yo need to configure `0x1017.0` accordingly:
Write 0x1017.0 = 1000: `67D [8] 2B 17 10 00 E8 03 00 00`

This will let node 125 send heartbeat messages in a 1 second interval.

The heartbeat message produced by node 125 should look something like this: `77D [1] 05`
The COB-ID should be `0x700 + NodeID`; byte 1 indicates the NMT state.

You also have to configure the master as heartbeat consumer appropriately:
`0x1016.1: (NodeId << 16) | HeartbeatConsumerTime`

`NodeId`: node ID of the heartbeat producer
`HeartbeatConsumerTime`: it has to be greater that the heartbeat producer time (in ms)

For example, for node 125 and 2000 ms: `(125 << 16) | 2000 = 0x007D07D0`

Object `0x1016` is defined as an array of UNSIGNED32 values. `0x1016.0` holds the number of entries, which is read-only. For example when `0x1016.0 = 8`, then the heartbeat consumer can consume up to 8 heartbeat producer messages, which means sub-indices 1 to 8 are available.

---

An excerpt from [CiA 301](https://www.can-cia.org/groups/specifications/).

**Object 0x1016: Consumer Heartbeat Time**

[image: Structure of Consumer Heartbeat Time]

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Index | 0x1016 |
| Name | Consumer heartbeat time |
| Object code | ARRAY |
| Data type | UNSIGNED32 |
| Category | Optional |

Entry Description:

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Sub-index | 0x00 |
| Description | Highest sub-index supported |
| Entry category | Mandatory |
| Access | const |
| PDO mapping | No |
| Value range | 0x01 to 0x7F |
| Default value | profile- or manufacturer-specific |

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Sub-index | 0x01 |
| Description | Consumer heartbeat time |
| Entry category | Mandatory |
| Access | rw |
| PDO mapping | No |
| Value range | UNSIGNED32 (Figure 62) |
| Default value | 0x00000000 |

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Sub-index | 0x02 to 0x7F |
| Description | Consumer heartbeat time |
| Entry category | Optional |
| Access | rw |
| PDO mapping | No |
| Value range | UNSIGNED32 (Figure 62) |
| Default value | 0x00000000 |

**Object 0x1017: Producer Heartbeat Time**

Object Description:

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Index | 0x1017 |
| Name | Producer heartbeat time |
| Object code | VAR |
| Data type | UNSIGNED16 |
| Category | Conditional; Mandatory, if guarding not supported |

Entry Description:

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Sub-index | 0x00 |
| Access | rw; const, if default value is profile-specific and not changeable |
| PDO mapping | No |
| Value range | UNSIGNED16 |
| Default value | 0 or profile-specific |

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. How can I convert the dump data to text form? Regarding the changes you comented, I'm going to try now and I'll let you know as soon as I can.

Comment: In some Linux terminals you can simply select the text and paste it with the middle mouse button. In others you can right-click to open a context menu. (I don't know which terminal you're using.)

Comment: I'm using `gnome terminal: xterm`